# GenServer crashes the whole application when handling non-existing hande_call

Tags: elixir

I intentionally call the nonexisting function in GenServer in order to see if the Supervisor will restart it after it crashes, like this:

```
GenServer.call(:global.whereis_name("MyServer"), {:doesnotexist, ""})
```

and it not only crashes the process, but the whole application is killed off. The terminate function will fire off and show that the handle_call does not handles the :doesnotexist as it does not exist.

And yes, I have created the supervisor and used start_child, and in the child GenServer I have used `GenServer.start_link/3`, so all should work.

Same happens if I use `Process.exit(:global.whereis_name("MyServer"), :kill)` or `Process.exit(:global.whereis_name("MyServer"), :normal)`, nothing gets restarted.

The supervision tree is:

```elixir
def start(_type,_args) do
  opts = [stategy: :one_for_one, name: MySupervisor]
  DynamicSupervisor.start_link(opts)
  DynamicSupervisor.start_child(MySupervisor, {MyServer, "MyServer"})
end
```

And the server starts like this:

```elixir
GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, String.to_atom(id))
```

The error message I get back:

```erlang
MyServer has terminated: 
  {:function_clause,
    [{MyServer, :handle_call,
      [{:something, ""}, {#PID<0.200.0>, [:alias | #Reference<0.2456789572.2609709057.49272>]}, :MyServer],
    [file: 'lib/my_server.ex', line: 46]},
  {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 721]},
  {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 750]},
  {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 226]}]}
```

Comment: Please show a) your supervision tree, and b) the full error message printed out.

Comment: All is just regular, the supervisor:  `def start(_type,_args) do
opts = [stategy: :one_for_one, name: MySupervisor]  
DynamicSupervisor.start_link(opts)  
DynamicSupervisor.start_child( MySupervisor, {MyServer, "MyServer"})  
end`  

End the server starts like this:
  `GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, String.to_atom(id))`

Comment: The message returned is: `MyServer has terminated: {:function_clause, [{MyServer, :handle_call, [{:something, ""}, {#PID<0.200.0>, [:alias | #Reference<0.2456789572.2609709057.49272>]}, :MyServer], [file: 'lib/my_server.ex', line: 46]}, {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 721]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 750]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 226]}]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start your `GenServer` unsupervised. The process you call `GenServer.start_link/2` from monitors the started `GenServer`, but I assume it [does not trap exits](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html), meaning when `GenServer` crashes, this process crashes as well, and then it crashes the `Application`.

You should either start it inside a supervision tree if you want it to start statically or with [`DynamicSupervisor.start_child/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DynamicSupervisor.html#start_child/2) if you want to start it dynamically.

---

After some clarifications, I am still unable to figure out why you get back the message you’ve posted because the server has no registered name and it `GenServer.call/2` should fail. Here is a working example without messing with registered names:

```elixir
iex||1 ▸ defmodule MyServer do            
...||1 ▸   use GenServer
...||1 ▸   def start_link(id),
...||1 ▸     do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, String.to_atom(id))
...||1 ▸ end

iex||2 ▸ opts = [stategy: :one_for_one, name: MySupervisor]
iex||3 ▸ DynamicSupervisor.start_link(opts)
iex||4 ▸ {:ok, pid} = DynamicSupervisor.start_child(MySupervisor, {MyServer, "MyServer"})
#⇒ {:ok, #PID<0.125.0>}

iex||5 ▸ DynamicSupervisor.which_children(MySupervisor)
#⇒ [{:undefined, #PID<0.125.0>, :worker, [MyServer]}]

iex||6 ▸ GenServer.call(pid, :doesnotexist) 
#⇒ Lot of error output

iex||7 ▸ DynamicSupervisor.which_children(MySupervisor)                         
#⇒ [{:undefined, #PID<0.132.0>, :worker, [MyServer]}]
```

As you can see, it got restarted with the new `pid`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I start it unsupervised. The supervisor does: `DynamicSupervisor.start_child( MySupervisor, {MyServer, "MyServer"})`, that is exactly that.

Comment: Please show the `start_link/1` function of `MyServer`, please.

Comment: It is up there in my previous comment: `GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, String.to_atom(id))`

Comment: Then something is wrong with your MCVE. I will update the answer to show it works, you’ll get it from there.

Comment: Done, so I’d suppose you should dig into server naming. _Sidenote:_ `String.to_atom(id)` is prone to atoms DoS attack and should be avoided. _Sidenote:_ https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration

Comment: Thank you….I know the String.to_atom should not be used, it was only for the example here. The naming should not mess things up, it just does: `:global.register_name(id, pid)`, so that later I can call `:global.whereis_name(“MyServer”)`, and that works, returns the pid and I can call the server, so that’s not it. Let me look into the code you posted, and I will get back to you, thanks.

Comment: Here’s what I found: your example works in iex, also with me, but my app still does not work. When I changed the supervisor from DynamicSupervisor.start_child to Supervisor.start_link, and gave it a list of children (with only one child), everything started to work and the server is restarted after a crash. Nothing else was changed, like naming etc. So go figure…why would the same server get restarted with Supervisor, but not with the DynamicSupervisor? I thought those were the same, just the former has a static list of children, and the latter a danimic one.

Comment: The issue is somewhere else. `DynamicSupervisor` and `Supervisor` work absolutely the same when it comes to supervision functionality.